# how to create button in internet explorer?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I am developing a simple c++ program inside Microsoft Visual Studio. This program will later be convert to DLL, in order to register it to Internet Explorer.

Inside my program, I would like to do like this:

```
 if flag=1,
   toolbar_button = green;
 else
   toolbar button = red;
```

I want to create a simple button on the Internet Explorer, and the button can reflects the color that I pass from my c++ program.

How can I achieve this?

Update: So far, I follow this manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588%28VS.85%29.aspx#details_script . I do it inside my Windows XP and IE8. It still does not work. No button appear on the IE toolbar.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you talking about BHO? Do you mean adding a toolbar button to IE?

Comment: I do not know about BHO since this is my first time using Visual Studio. Yes, I want to add a simple button on the IE.

Comment: Keep in mind that IE has changed a bit over time. In particular, IE8 has a new interface. Which version(s) do you need to support?

Comment: I am currently trying the steps inside this manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753588%28VS.85%29.aspx#details_script   . Currently, IE8 in the only I have. Maybe that is why it still does not work..